# iOS9 mobile safari landscape css bug with position: fixed;

Tags: ios, css

I checked this bug with **iOS9** mobile safari **iPhone6sPlus**.

I can't touch the fixed element when safari's tab is displayed in landscape mode. And I can touch it when the tab is hidden.

1. Show [my demo](http://s.codepen.io/geckotang/debug/yYZmoe) on iOS9 mobile safari landscape.

   - Reproduced successfully only with tab bar visible,
2. Scroll down until the tab was hidden.
3. Touch the fixed element.
4. Scroll up until the tab was displayed.
5. Maybe you can't touch the fixed element.

Do you know about this bug?

Please try to touch when the tab is displayed on my pen.
http://s.codepen.io/geckotang/debug/yYZmoe

This is the screenshot when I can't touch the element.

[image: landscape mode]

And my friend recorded the bug on [youtube](https://youtu.be/LXji-ol2A7U?t=27)

Plus this is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.fixed {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="fixed">link</a>
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<br>
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<br>
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<br>
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<br>
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<br>
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<br>
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<br>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce in iOS Simulator 9.0 - iPhone 6s / iOS 9.0.

Comment: Really? I checked in iPhone 6sPlus / iOS9.1. Thank you for teaching me.

Comment: Reproduced successfully only **with** tab bar visible, no other configurations.  The touch point is getting a vertical offset applied when scrolling with the tab bar on screen.  This is definitely an iOS bug and you should file a radar.  There's no obvious fix, maybe remove and readd the element when scrolling stops?

Comment: Still can't reproduce in iOS Simulator - iPhone 6s Plus / iOS 9.1. This is strange. This wouldn't be the first time I saw strange behavior on fixed elements in the simulator though. Has this been confirmed on a real device?

Comment: The simulator consistently fails to simulate issues. I am attempting to fix the same problem now. I'll report back here if I get anywhere.

Comment: This problem was fixed on iOS 10.3

Answer (score 2):

I am running iOS 9.3.1 on an iPhone 6S Plus and am seeing this problem also. After experimenting with numerous code workarounds I cannot resolve this or find a workaround. As stated above, it only occurs when the tab bar visible on the browser, as soon as you scroll down the page and the tab bar disappears, the rendering works as expected. When you scroll back up to the top of the page, the touch area is offset down by the amount of the page you had previously scrolled down to.

To note, this does not affect the visible rendering of the screen element in a fixed position, only the touch area associated with it.

Comment: thank you for checking on latest iOS. My friend reported this problem to Apple. However, it's not fixed.

Comment: I actually narrowed it down a little more. Since the tab bar is only visible on the 6 Plus or 6S Plus, this problem does not affected any other phone model, however it might affect iPads I haven't tested yet. Adding to that if someone has the tab bar turned off in the Safari app settings, they won't see it. Very narrow condition: 6/6S Plus, landscape mode, after screen has scrolled down and back up page, only when tab bar is visible.

Comment: Just want to add to the mix... I can confirm this issue does indeed also exist  on a standard iPhone 6 (not plus) running iOS 9.3.4. Visible rendering is correct, touch area is offset (wrong). Pretty rough issue as I've also tried all kinds of tricks to try and force a redraw, fire scroll events, etc. with no luck yet.

Comment: … and it's still there in iOS 10.